# How to fill a StackPanel inside of a UserControl?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am creating a custom panel which is basically just a fancier `StackPanel` with some added functionality. I was going to use a `UserControl` which contains a `StackPanel` but I don't know how to make my `UserControl` accept content to fill it's `StackPanel`.

This is what I'm trying:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="transformations.fold_panel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:transformations"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Content="First" />
        <ContentControl Content="{x:Bind Content, Mode=OneWay}"></ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Usage:

```
<local:fold_panel>
     <Button Content="Second" />
</local:fold_panel>
```

When I try this I get the following error:
`WinRT originate error - 0x80070057 : 'The parameter is incorrect.'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind the `Content` of a `StackPanel` in a `UserControl`'s `Content` to the `Content` property of the same `UserControl`. This will introduce a circular reference.

In your example, the `Content` property of the `fold_panel` `UserControl` will be set to the `StackPanel` that you defined in the XAML markup.

If you want to be able to set the `Content` of the `ContentControl` in the `StackPanel`, you should add a [custom dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-dependency-properties) to the `fold_panel` class and bind the `Content` property of the `ContentControl` to this one:

```
<ContentControl Content="{x:Bind CustomContent, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

You can then set your custom property something like this:

```
<local:fold_panel>
    <local:fold_panel.CustomContent>
        <Button Content="Second" />
    <local:fold_panel.CustomContent>
</local:fold_panel>
```

But if you really want a custom `StackPanel`, you should create a class that inherits from `StackPanel` rather than `UserControl`.